# What is the difference between Puppeteer and Electron with respect to using it to test client side of an app

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, electron, puppeteer, lit-element

I have been rushing to get my app, a mixture between nodejs server driving an sqlite database and a litElement based client side providing the ui, into a useable state as a beta release.  I achieved that a couple of days ago and now I am (belatedly I know) thinking how to put together a test framework.  However I am really struggling to understand how to best test the client side.  I think its because I am having difficulty understanding conceptually what the two main choices of framework are.  Before I go into more detail, let me explain the structure of the app in top level terms.

At the project root level there are three main directories `node_modules` which comprises all the modules I've pulled in (including `lit-element` and `web-components-loader` which are client side elements - but see below) `server` which contains all the code for the server side of my application and `client` which consist of all the code for the client side of my app.  I run `rollup` ONLY at module install time to "package" lit-element and the directives I use and the web-component-loader and effectively treeshake and copy them to the `client/libs`.  As a result of this my client is coded to assume the modules are in the libs directory AND I DO NOT NEED OR HAVE any build stage. I guess the root of the client is `index.html` which pulls in a `service-worker.js` and `main-app.js`. `main-app` is the root of a tree in `lit-element` based components that make up the entire client app.  Nginx is the web server for all the static files in the client, but also acts as a proxy to pass any urls that start `/api` to a standard node http web server (not even `express`, although I do use the `router`, `body-parser` and `final-handler` modules) and these get passed to various api handlers each of which is a separate javascript file - although these can "require" a few common modules that I have written and those in the `node_modules` directory.

I plan on using `jest` as a test environment.  For my server I think it is easy.  For each api handler I want to test I can build a test script that "requires" the javascript file I want to test.  I am in two minds about whether to use a sqlite database for testing or mock something - I am leaning towards the former as I am using better-sqlite3 and it is totally synchronous and very fast.  I already have scripts to create empty databases, so I have no worry about test isolation.

Client testing is where I get confused.  I "think" that in essence jest can run tests the same way as for the server, one element at a time.  BUT, these elements and my test scripts are going to need a "web-platform" set of APIs - not least of which is the entire shadow dom and custom components stuff that lit-element uses.  This is where, I think, `puppeteer` or `electron` in with there associated jest plugins which can put these platform apis into the test environment. But, and this is the essence of my confusion, puppeteer instructions all start with a something like

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(SOME URL);
```

What is this URL? - do I have to also run a server?   I cannot relate this snippet to running a test controlled by jest. All the examples seem to use `webpack` and `typescript`, neither of which I know anything about.

The other module I have seen mentioned is `electron`, in particular this article, which everything else seems to point to (or the same text).

https://www.ninkovic.dev/blog/2020/testing-web-components-with-jest-and-lit-element

From the code snippets in this article it "seems" like it might be what I want, BUT ...
I cannot find very many references to electron other than on its own web site.  Here it is telling you to use electron as a tool to build a cross platform application, but nowhere can I find what it is - it assumes you already know.  I don't want a UI for my unit testing I want it to be headless like in puppeteer.

Hence my confusion and why I am unsure how to achieve what I want.  Can someone give me some pointers as to

- How can I set up puppeteer to run headless tests without needing a server OR
- What exactly is electron (and can I use it to
  a) run my tests
  b) provide me with tools to examine the dom elements I have created to see I have created the right ones) and how is it different from puppeteer and can I use it to conduct headless tests of my client.

UPDATE

I've done some more digging and am beginning to understand the differences.  Let me summarise what I think I have found.

- Puppeteer is great for end to end testing of your site.  You run the tests by launching the included puppeteer at the home page of your site (or the more likely scenario of a development test site) and programatically pretend to be a user who can click on buttons etc.  You can use various methods, including functions such as `document.querySelector()` to check your UI has behaved how you think, or you can take screen shots and compare with standardised version. I could possible use it for unit tests, but I would have to run a server, create a test fixture html page for every test and navigate to it.  `jest-puppeteer` is a package with some of that built in.
- Electron is a platform for building apps.  What the url I was referencing was using a test runner app `jest-electron` built using electron.  So worrying about `electron` is a red herring, I should be worrying about `jest-electron`.

My main concern right now, I think, is that I need different jest configurations for my three scenarios

- unit tests on the server
- unit tests on the client
- end to end testing of the complete app.

Given I have only one `package.json` file and one set of `node_modules` I need to figure out a way to have three different `jest-config.js` files.

Comment: Electron is for packaging "web-view" type desktop apps. For testing you want puppeteer/playwright or selenium.

Comment: @pguardiario I've updated the question as a result of more digging.  I think that update is probably also a reply to your comment. I had not heard of playwright before, which does slightly complicate things, although I think that is a choice I can delay making.

Comment: I recommend playwright, it's what the original puppeteer team and many involved in chromium development have moved on to. It's really frowned on to solicit advice like this here but that's my 2 cents. Also check out mocha vs jest.

Comment: I've used mocha (along with chai and sinon) a lot in the past, jest just seemed to be simpler by bundling it all together.  I've also come across cypress in my searches this weekend which also looks interesting.